# File editing in a remote Linux machine?

Tags: java, linux

I am writing a Java code for Linux RHEL 5 machine. The requirement is that while sitting at machine A, I should be able to edit some files in a remote machine B. Both machine A & B are RHEL. Now the following possibilities are there. Can anyone please suggest which is better or if any  other way is there:

1. Write a shell script to do this. Execute the shell script from A such that changes happen in B
2. Write a java code on A, that is able to login to B and edit files in B.
3. Write a java file editing utility (pattern-matching thing). Push this util on B through another java code. Execute the file edit util in B. Somehow the trigger for executing the util in B should also be given by A

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Remote System Explorer lets you do just that: http://www.eclipse.org/tm/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use java library to do that :

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Check out the examples link.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs but I think it is easier and faster to do that with bash scripts and some linux tools like nc, telnet or ssh for instance.

With ssh is as simple as:

```
ssh user@remote mkdir /tmp/new_directory
```

I hope it helps...